# angular how to animate with dynamic property

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-animations

I would like to create an animatoin based on variable. For example there is a div with 0px width and on click evetn change its width an animated way, but the size its new width based on a parameter, which comes from the click event function. Furthermore it should  to animate the width form its current position, for example if its current width 50px and the new width 100px, than the animation should start with 50px not 0px.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-anim',
    templateUrl: './anim.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./anim.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        trigger('state', [
            state('inactive', style({
                'width' : currentWidth //the current width to start from
            })),
            state('active', style({
                'width': newWith //<=== how to use variable here?
            })),
            transition('inactive => active', animate('4000ms ease-in'))
        ])
    ]
})
export class AnimComponent {
    public state = 'inactive';

    constructor () {}

    public ngOnInit(){

    }

    public resize(width){
        this.newWidth = width;
        this.state = 'active';

        this.currentWidth = width;
    }
}
```

//the event

```
<div class="row-chart-result" [@state]="state" (click)="resize('150px')"></div>
```

What is the suggested way to use animation based on variables?